# why aren't the inside sides of the shape showing when I export it as a .STL file

Tags: mesh

[image]
why aren't the inside sides of the shape showing when I export it as a .STL file. I have tried Alt F, F and Control F grid fill.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe the normals of you model are wrong. If the normal of a face is pointing inside the mesh, it may not be displayed by some renderers. When in edit mode, you can display the normals of the model using the right pane in the 3D view (section *Mesh Display* > normals). Try to call *Make Normals Consistent* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>) when editing your mesh.